# postgres how to filter results of jsonb_agg()

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

The following query parses a text column in a table to obtain a 'PO' value.  It then returns a table with two columns - 'PO' and 'DATA' where each cell essentially contains all the row data as a JSONB object:

```
select POed."PO", jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(POed)- 'PO') as "DATA"
from (
    select  * , 
        (case 
            when patd."Text" notnull
            then (regexp_match(patd."Text" , '^[0-9]{10}00'))[1]
            else null
        end) as "PO"
    from "pat_details" patd
    ) as POed
group by "PO"
```

A simpler example is if I start with a table:

| a | b | Text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | xxx 453 yyy |
| 4 | 5 | www 453 www |

The result looks like this where each element of DATA is a list of json objects:

| PO | DATA |
| --- | --- |
| 453 | [{"a": 1, "b":2},{"a": 4, "b":5}] |

I want to further filter the result to show say all "PO" with "a"=4.  I thought something like:

```
WHERE "DATA" -> 0 -> 0."a" = "4"
```

That generates a syntax error.  What is the error/correct way to query this?

*Note 1*:  WHERE "DATA"->0->>'a'='4' will get me all instances where the first element of the list has the criteria but then do I have to repeat the query for all possible elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

```
WHERE "DATA"@>'[{"a":"4"}]'
```

Note that if you try to specify a specific element as I did you will run in to problems.  It looks like the elements in the jsonb are randomly ordered so if you (as I did) search on the first element, you will probably get a different answer each query.